# Calling a method for a 2d array in java

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, methods, 2d

I am doing an assignment for a programming class involving a heuristic for a Knight's tour. At the moment I have a method that is meant to fill an 8x8 chessboard array with "Board" objects that know the "accessability" of that space on the board as well as if that board has been actually visited before. However, when I create the 8x8 array and try to call my "fill" method for this array I get an error telling me that the array does not exist in the package I am using...what am I doing wrong here? Shouldn't it be as simple as declaring the array and calling the method with

```
Board [][] chessboard = new Board [8][8];
chessboard.fill();
```

Or is my syntax wrong? For reference here is my code that creates my Board objects, my accessibility matrix, and then copies those accessibility values to each Board object on my 8x8 array. Thanks!

```
public class Board {

/*
 * Initialize array that emulates chessboard. Will be 8x8, each space will 
 * contain the number of squares from which that space can be reached. The 
 * knight will start at a new space each tour and choose each move based on
 * the "accessability" of each square within its "move pool". The knight 
 * will move to the square with least accesibility each time. When the 
 * Knight is moved to a square, this square will be marked as visited so 
 * that it cannot be visited again. Also, any space that could have been 
 * moved to but was not will have its accesability reduced by 1.     
 */

private boolean visited;
private int accessValue;
private Board [][] chess = new Board[8][8];

public Board(int acessability, boolean beenVisited)
{
    visited = beenVisited;
    accessValue = acessability;  
}

int [][] accessMatrix = {{2,3,4,4,4,4,3,2},
                        { 3,4,6,6,6,6,4,3 },
                        { 4,6,8,8,8,8,6,4 },
                        { 4,6,8,8,8,8,6,4 },
                        { 4,6,8,8,8,8,6,4 },
            { 4,6,8,8,8,8,6,4 },
            { 3,4,6,6,6,6,4,3 },
            { 2,3,4,4,4,4,3,2}};





public void fill()
{

for (int i = 0 ; i < accessMatrix.length ; i++)
{
    chess[0][i].changeAccess(accessMatrix[0][i]);
}
for (int i = 0 ; i < accessMatrix.length ; i++)
{
    chess[1][i].changeAccess(accessMatrix[1][i]);
}
for (int i = 0 ; i < accessMatrix.length ; i++)
{
    chess[2][i].changeAccess(accessMatrix[2][i]);
}
for (int i = 0 ; i < accessMatrix.length ; i++)
{
    chess[3][i].changeAccess(accessMatrix[3][i]);
}
for (int i = 0 ; i < accessMatrix.length ; i++)
{
    chess[4][i].changeAccess(accessMatrix[4][i]);
}
for (int i = 0 ; i < accessMatrix.length ; i++)
{
    chess[5][i].changeAccess(accessMatrix[5][i]);
}
for (int i = 0 ; i < accessMatrix.length ; i++)
{
    chess[6][i].changeAccess(accessMatrix[6][i]);
}
for (int i = 0 ; i < accessMatrix.length ; i++)
{
    chess[7][i].changeAccess(accessMatrix[7][i]);
}

}   




public int getAccess()
{
return accessValue;
}

public int changeAccess(int newAccess)
{
int accessNew;
accessNew = newAccess;
return accessNew;    
}
```

Comment: Board [] chessboard = new Board [8][8]; should be Board [][] chessboard = new Board [8][8];

Comment: `chessboard` is an array, not a Board, so you can't call the `fill` method on it.

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
Board [] chessboard = new Board [8][8];
```

the type of a `Board[8][8]` is `Board[][]`

So it should be written that way to compile:

```
Board [][] chessboard = new Board [8][8];
```

(then you will have to create each Board() objects inside your array, I left that to you as an exercise)

And in this code:

```
chessboard.fill();
```

You are calling a method of Board. You can only do that on a Board object, not on an array. If you want to call this method on each board object in your array, you have to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i <8; i ++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j ++){
         chessboard[i][j].fill();
    }
}
```

But I feel there is more to it, as there is some confusion. A chessboard, I think, is a board, not an array of board. You are probably wanting to create one chessboard and fill it once. Right? Then simply do this:

```
 Board chessboard = new Board();
 chessboard.fill();
```

Comment: I thought that when I created the array of type Board, each element of the array is filled with an empty Board object that can be modified?

Comment: No, when you create an array of objects (as opposed to an array of primitive types), each element of the array is `null`, so you have to create them yourself.

Comment: Also, I don't see why the fill method is of type Board and not Board[][] if it is working with the Board[8][8] called "chess". Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The fact that the `fill` method work internally with a `Board[8][8]` or with anything of any type is irrelevant. It is a non-static method of the class `Board` and therefore can only be called on an instance of `Board`.

Comment: I see, and for the record I am actually creating the chessboard 64 times and re-filling it each time in another class. Is there any way to just make the fill method work with an instance of Board[][]?

Comment: No, you can't. If you are trying to do that, maybe your overall design is wrong. Ask yourself three questions. 1, what does your Board class represents: a board or a square? 2, why would a board also contain an array of Board[8][8], that is references to 64 other Board instances? 3, why are you creating 64 chessboard in the first place?